# Updating an observable collection from a parent component in Aurelia

Tags: typescript, data-binding, aurelia, web-component, aurelia-templating

To better understand interactions between Aurelia components, I've separated the list component of the Todo List app in Aurelia's [quick start documentation](https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-todo-app) into its own class and corresponding view. But doing so leads to the view not updating when a new element is added to the list.

My modified code is as follows:

**app.html:**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./todo-list"></require>
  <h1>Todo list</h1>
  <form submit.trigger="addTodo()">
    <input type="text" value.bind="todoDescription">
    <button type="submit" disabled.bind="!todoDescription">Add Todo</button>
  </form>
  <todo-list></todo-list>
</template>
```

**app.ts:**

```ts
import { TodoList } from "todo-list";
export class App {
  todoList: TodoList = new TodoList();
  todoDescription = '';

  addTodo() {
    if (this.todoDescription) {
      this.todoList.addOne(this.todoDescription);
      this.todoDescription = '';
    }
  }
}
```

**todo-list.html**

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="todo of todos">
      <input type="checkbox" checked.bind="todo.done">
      <span css="text-decoration: ${todo.done ? 'line-through' : 'none'}">
        ${todo.description}
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</template>
```

**todo-list.ts:**

```ts
export interface Todo {
  description: string;
  done: boolean;
}

export class TodoList {
  todos: Todo[] = [
    { description: "Make bed", done: true },
    { description: "Take out trash", done: false }
  ];

  addOne(todoDescription: string) {
    this.todos.push({
      description: todoDescription,
      done: false
    });
  }
}
```

The original, working code is as follows:

**app.ts:**

```ts
export interface Todo {
  description: string;
  done: boolean;
}

export class App {
  todos: Todo[] = [
    {description: "Make bed", done: true}, 
    {description: "Take out trash", done: false}
  ];
  todoDescription = '';

  addTodo() {
    if (this.todoDescription) {
      this.todos.push({
        description: this.todoDescription,
        done: false
      });
      this.todoDescription = '';
    }
  }
}
```

**app.html:**

```html
<template>
  <h1>Todo list</h1>

  <form submit.trigger="addTodo()">
    <input type="text" value.bind="todoDescription">
    <button type="submit" disabled.bind="!todoDescription">Add Todo</button>
  </form>

  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="todo of todos">
      <input type="checkbox" checked.bind="todo.done">
      <span css="text-decoration: ${todo.done ? 'line-through' : 'none'}">
        ${todo.description}
      </span>
      <button click.trigger="removeTodo(todo)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Debugging shows that after the classes are separated, the `todos` array is indeed updated, but the view is not.

How can I modify my existing code so that when a new element is added to the todo list, the view is updated accordingly?

Comment: How are you passing the list object to the **todo-list** component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aurelia creates an instance of TodoList when it sees the  element.  You have created a separate instance when you "newed" it up.  Instead of creating a new instance of the TodoList class, you should use view-model.ref to capture a reference to the instance aurelia has created.

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./todo-list"></require>
  <h1>Todo list</h1>
  <form submit.trigger="addTodo()">
    <input type="text" value.bind="todoDescription">
    <button type="submit" disabled.bind="!todoDescription">Add Todo</button>
  </form>
  <todo-list view-model.ref="todoList"></todo-list>
</template>
```

**app.ts**

```
import { TodoList } from "todo-list";
export class App {
  todoList: TodoList;
  todoDescription = '';

  addTodo() {
    if (this.todoDescription) {
      this.todoList.addOne(this.todoDescription);
      this.todoDescription = '';
    }
  }
}
```